# creditor - apply external stylesheet to the inner text in CKEditor textarea

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

I know similar question has been asked so much, but what I want is something else.

I like CKEditor but there is one thing bothering me, the inline styles. I want to get rid of it. 
I have added this code to customise the drop down list:

```
    CKEDITOR.stylesSet.add( 'default', [
                // Block Styles
                { name: 'Blue Title',       element: 'h3',      attributes: { 'class': 'Blue' } },
                { name: 'Red Title',        element: 'h3',      attributes: { 'class': 'Red' } },

                // Inline Styles
                { name: 'Marker: Yellow',   element: 'span',    attributes: { 'class': 'Yellow' } },
                { name: 'Marker: Green',    element: 'span',    attributes: { 'class': 'Lime' } }


            ] );
```

as you can see I didn't use any style for the elements, just classes. Now when I click the drop down list and select any of them, I get this:

```
<p><span class="Yellow">this is a paragraph</span></p>
```

which is good. BUT the drop down list has no style, and the text hasn't changed in the WYSIWYG textarea.

I tried

```
CKEDITOR.config.contentsCss = '/myStyle.css';
```

and put this code in it

```
#Yellow{
background-color: #ffff00;
}

#Lime{
background-color: lime;
}
```

but still nothing happens.

I use 'stylesparser' and 'stylescombo' plugins but still no luck. (or maybe I don't know how to configure them)

I have tried to put those lines of css in contents.css file but nothing happened.

I wanna know, is what I'm asking is possible in CKEditor? If Yes, How? If No, Is there any other editor which will give me this feature?

thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

well after digging so much into every thing, I found out that I'm using '#' sing in my css to define class style. after changing it to '.' everything goes as I expected. No inline styles and when I apple the style to a paragraph or a text, it becomes visual and there is no need for any extra plugin.